# Using subquery data to filter the main SQL query for TableAdapters

Tags: sql, asp.net, tableadapter

This is basically a SQL question, on how to use data from a subselect to filter your main query.  I am using tableadapters but the question is how to do this in SQL without using joins. i am using tableadapters and ASP.NET as described in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx

my problem is how to stick to the idea of NOT using joins for my tableadapters (reasons are  discussed in the article).  i have 2 tables: Phones and PhoneAssociations.  the Phones table contains things like phoneID, cellNumber, name, etc.  the PhonesAssociations table contains info about which phones (one to many) are associated with that phone. it contains things like associationID, phoneID, addedByID.  i want to create a query for the tableadapter that returns the phones data (cell, ID, name) that have been added by a single ID.

if i am not filtering the data and want to return all the phones and associated data the sql is simple:

```
SELECT 
phoneID, 
cellNumber,
providerID, 
password, 
nickname,  
added, 
(SELECT     
addedByID
FROM PhoneAssociations pa
WHERE p.phoneID = pa.addedByID) AS addedByID
FROM Phones AS p
```

but what i cant seem to figure out how to do without using joins is filter that list by the addedByID, the following doesnt work:

```
SELECT 
phoneID, 
cellNumber,
providerID, 
password, 
nickname,  
added, 
(SELECT     
addedByID
FROM PhoneAssociations pa
WHERE p.phoneID = pa.addedByID) AS addedByID
FROM Phones AS p 
WHERE addedBYID=1
```

this also doesnt work:

```
WHERE pa.addedBYID=1
```

this is pretty simple using joins, but i am not finding the syntax for doing it using subselects.  any SQL gurus out there that can point me in the right direction?  If you look at the article you will see the need to use subselects instead of joins so that the tableadapters can create your update, delete and insert methods.  Thanks!

the records that need to be returned should retain their original phoneID, i need a list of all the phones (with their phoneID's) that have been added by the phoneID of 12 – contractorwolf 16 mins ago

i added this in the comments, but maybe i should clarify in the question itself:

if im being more clear, and there are 3 records in the phones table with phoneIDs of 4,8 and 12 and 2 records in the PhoneAssociations table with phoneIDs of 4 and 8 and addedByIDs of 12 what i need to return is 2 records that have phoneIDs of 4 and 8 because they both were addedByID by 12

```
Phones
4
8
12
```

and

```
PhoneAssociations (addedByID is second column)
4, 12
8, 12
```

what i am trying to answer is: what phoneIDs were added by phoneID 12? thx

Answer (score 1):

```
Select phoneID
    , cellNumber, providerID, password
    , nickname, added
    , phoneID As addedByID
From Phones AS p 
Where phoneID = 1
    And Exists  (
                Select 1
                From PhoneAssociations As PA1
                Where PA1.addedByID = P.phoneID
                )
```

Comment: Hmm, correct me if I'm wrong here but that seems to return a list of phones that HAVE an associated addedByID, but doesn't filter to a specific addedByID, I need to know that phones associated with a particular ID

Comment: @contractorwolf - It does by virtue of the filter `phoneID = 1` which you were matching to `PhoneAssociations.addedByID`.

Comment: the records that need to be returned should retain their original phoneID, i need a list of all the phones (with their phoneID's) that have been added by the phoneID of 12

Comment: if im being more clear, and there are 3 records in the phones table with phoneIDs of 4,8 and 12 and 2 records in the PhoneAssociations table with phoneIDs of 4 and 8 and addedByIDs of 12 what i need to return is 2 records that have phoneIDs of 4 and 8 because they both were addedByID by 12

Comment: what i am trying to answer is: what phoneIDs were added by phoneID 12?

Comment: @contractorwolf - Cool. Glad you found your solution. Sorry I wasn't able to get back to you sooner.

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas - I modified your approach a little to give me the data that I needed.
The final Query I used (in case anyone else is looking to solve this sort of problem) is here:

```
SELECT 
phoneID, 
cellNumber, 
providerID, 
password, 
fullName, 
nickname, 
(SELECT 
    providerName 
FROM dbo.CellProviders AS cp 
WHERE p.providerID=cp.providerID) AS providerName 
FROM dbo.Phones as p 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PhoneAssociations AS pa 
WHERE pa.phoneID = p.phoneID 
AND pa.addedByID = @addedByID)
```

which allows me to pass an `addedByID` and return the phones associated with it with their correct `phoneID`.
Thanks again @Thomas for your answer, it totally bridged the gap for me.
The statement itself says "give me the phone data where their exists a relationship to `PhoneAssociations` with these records `phoneIDs` and the `AddedByID` of 12 (or whatever the @addedByID parameter needs to be). Hope that helps!